# CakePHP Shell - Fatal Error - Can't find 'AppModel' or shell just lists model classes

Tags: shell, cakephp

Background:
- Running CakePHP 2.3 on wAMP stack on Windows 7
- CakePHP Console was set up a couple weeks back and my initial scripts seemed to work fine: no errors and the information updated properly.
-After a couple weeks coding hiatus, I've returned to the same scripts and now, aftre trying to get them to run again, I get fatal errors in the console.
- I have not updated any files or updated CakePHP core in the interim.
- I may have added a bit of code to the shell after my last test (on the same day a few weeks back), though I tried removing any possible 'new' code and even tried running the simple 'HelloShell' to no avail.

Errors:
- Initially I got a 'Fatal Error: can't find the 'AppModel' file', which pointed me to the very first custom model in my Model folder.
I did some research and tried adding 'App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');' to the top of the indicated model file.
This removed the fatal error, though now running /any/ console script IE 'cake console hello' - the Hello World script listed on the CookBook - does not run the script. Instead, it lists all my current Model classes in a long line.

Method I am Using:
I open a comand prompt.
I navigate to my 'App' older.
I type:
cake console 
I get the problems isted above (either the error or the list of model classes if I've added the uses statement to the first model file I have.)

The ap si working fine in the browser - I receive no errors or exceptions. I've never had 'App::uses' at the top of any of my files beforeand the shell had worked previously.

Do I really have to go through and add this to the top of all my files or is there something else missing indicated by the fact the console is listing all my model files when I try to run a script? Granted - I am very new to the shell/console to begin with and I am not sure where else to turn to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be one of those 'I can't believe how stupidly simple it was.' - I was adding another word to the console command and it was thusly confusing CakePHP and confusing me with its random brokeness. Either way - error fixed!